# URL rewrite through an entry.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, clean-urls

I have two directory under my application directory

```
my_app:
  .htaccess
  lib:
    entry.php
  web:
    css:
      css_file1
      css_file2
    js:
      js_file1
      js_file2
```

My url will be like this http://example.com/my_app/my_path

Under the directory **my_app**, there are two directories **web** and **lib**.

If the **my_path** can be map to any file under the **web** directory, use it.

For example, http://example.com/my_app/css/css_file1 should map to **my_app/web/css/css_file1**.

Otherwise redirect it to **lib/entry.php/my_path** so that the the **my_path** can be accessed through **$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']** The redirection should be internal. The redirection should not be visible to user.

I want to write configuration in **.htaccess** to accomplish it.
I wrote the code as given below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule (.*) ../web/$1  
    RewriteCond web/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond web/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule (.*) lib/entry.php/$1 
</IfModule>
```

But I am getting 403 error.

Comment: DOCUMENT_ROOT is /var/www. But my_app is at /var/www/my_app.

Comment: Add a rewrite rule to rewrite every page hit (if file does not exist) to a URL param. So in root htaccess, rewrite /my_app/foo/bar to /?q=my_app/foo/bar. Now execute proper calls in the index file at the root.

Answer (score 1):

I believe following should work for you in `/var/www/.htaccess` i.e. directly under `$DOCUMENT_ROOT`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/web/$2 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/web/$2 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ $1/web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ $1/lib/entry.php/$2 [L]
```

Comment: The configuration depends on the directory my_app. If I change the my_app directory to another directory your_app. I have to change the configuration. I don't think the dependency is good one.

Comment: I didn't get your comment. According to your question you have .htaccess right under my_app and that's where my code should go in.

Comment: I want to create a simple php-frame work to handle clean-url. The .haccess is a core file. The end-user won't change it for his application directory.

Comment: But are you going to have individual .htaccess in each individual app dir? e.g. will `my_app/.htaccess` and `your_app/.htaccess` will be 2 different fiels?

Comment: The my_app and your_app is application directory name. If I am using the frame work for a blog, I will put it in a directory my_blog. The only change is my_app became my_blog.

Comment: I understand both of them are directory names but I still didn't get where the .htaccess file will be?

Comment: @habeebperwad: Please check the edited version now which is independent of my_app or you_app directory names. Just make sure above code is places in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file.